# Jquery plugin compatibility for Bootstrap radio buttons and toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a series of radio buttons using boostrap version 3.3.7. I have also added a functionality such that when I click on one of those buttons the color of the radio button has to permanently change to blue. it all works fine when I load jQuery plugin with version bootstrap as shown below

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But this will cause an error to toggle button which I have implemented and it is supposed to work as a dropdown list. If I Reverse the order in which jquery and bootstrap have been loaded then the dropdown will work all good causing an error with radio buttons. I would like to mention that radio button and toggle button are different features which I am working on. This has become a tricky problem to solve. Could I know which version of jquery would work for both the features which can be compatible with Bootstrap version 3.3.7 Please find the code below.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i>
        Dashboard
    </a>
    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" name="MontageSwap" id="MontageSwap"
       onchange="montageSwap(this.value);">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>
        Montage
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#" id="1" ">Car</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2" ">Bus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3" ">Bicycle</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<style>
    .btn-default {
        color: #D8D8D8;
        background-color: #D8D8D8;
        border-color: #D8D8D8;
    }

    .btn-default:hover {
        background-color: #5F5A66;
    }

    .btn-default.active {
        background-color: #4A90E2;
    }

</style>
<div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-10 col-xs-8" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">

            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="off"
                       onchange="dataSegment(0)" checked>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
            </label>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.btn.btn-default').on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

**How radio buttons are supposed to work**

[image]

**How they are actually working for me**

[image]

Comment: Where is `dataSegment` fn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the compatibility of bootstrap and jquery. When you are using a radio button, there can only be one active button. And since you added blue color only to those with active class, upon clicking another button, the active class gets transferred to the newly clicked button. 
The only reason why the radio button gets fixed when you switch the position of the jquery and bootstrap is because bootstrap is not working anymore and causes bugs. The best way you can achieve the behavior that you want is by using checkbox instead of radio.

But if you want to insist on using radio button, you need to make another class for your color. Here's what I did, from your css code:

```
.btn-default.active {
   background-color: #4A90E2;
 }
```

I changed it to:

```
.btn-default.color {
   background-color: #4A90E2;
}
```

and added:

```
.btn-default.focus{
   background-color: #4A90E2 !important;
}
```

to override the `focus` class when you click on the element.

for the script, i changed the `active` to `color`

```
$('.btn.btn-default').on("click", function () {
    $(this).addClass('color');
});
```

To get rid of the small square below the bar that you created, I added this:

```
input[type=radio]{
   margin-top:-6px;
}
```

You may visit the JSBin sample [here](http://jsbin.com/ticagim/edit?html,css,output)

As you can see there, both the functions are working fine. :)

Comment: I agree with this answer.

Comment: awesome I will test it soon. Thanks for your input.